# App Previews for iPhone 6+, using an other iOS device

Tags: ios-appstore

I'm trying to create an App Preview Video for a game we did.
I recorded using QuickTime, plus iMovie to create it. I recorded the videos with iPhone 5, iPhone 6 and iPad.

But I don't have an iPhone 6 Plus to record on 1920x1080. So my question is, will users who are on an iPhone 6 Plus see the video or only the screenshots?

I read some similar topics, but the answers were contradicted.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create one specifically for iPhone 6Plus according to this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW10